# Watson Concept insight deprecated. What's next?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi, concept-insights

After you train a model using Knowledge Studio, how do you do Conceptual Search (previous function in Concept Insight which allows you to send a document ID to return a list of document IDs of similar documents).
In AlchemyLanguage is not possible.
And documentation how to implement/integrate this?
Any info much appreciated.

Comment: Your best option is to look at the Discovery service. https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/discovery/